# Изменить прямоугольник фокуса на MenuItem

Tags: c#, wpf

Когда наводим мышкой на MenuItem на нем рисуется прямоугольник фокуса, как изменить его цвет фона и цвет рамки, шаблон? Не нашел в шаблоне MenuItem про него ничего

Answer (score 4, accepted):

То, что вы имеете ввиду, это не фокус, фокус может (и обычно всегда) находиться на другом пункте меню или на другом контроле. Вам же нужен *выделенный* (highlighted) пункт меню, соответственно, в шаблоне элемента смотрите триггер

```
<Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="True">
```

именно он срабатывает при наведении курсора на пункт меню, в частности, здесь меняется цвет рамки:

```
<Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Bg">
    <Setter.Value>
        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
            <GradientStop Color="#34C5EBFF" Offset="0"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#3481D8FF" Offset="1"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Если в градиенте заменить первый цвет на Red, а второй на Green, то получится вот что:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я бы ещё добавил, что то, что нужно ТС — это не фокус.